# How to control parts of a CSS file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a webpage, where I can change background color, font style and size by 9 different buttons.

Problem #1 here is I'm using one css file for every single button,
and problem #2 is that when for example changing background color to blue, and I want to change the font style to cursive, I cant have 2 active at the same time, the other one goes back to default.

Any advice on how to do this?

Here are my CSS and HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link id="pagestyle" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>
    function swapStyleSheet(sheet){
        document.getElementById('pagestyle').setAttribute('href', sheet);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CSS 1 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('')"><a href="#">Bytt skrift</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('skrift1.css')"><a href="#">Bytt farge</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('background1.css')"><a href="#">Bytt bakgrunnsfarget</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CSS 2 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('')"><a href="#">Bytt skrift</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('skrift2.css')"><a href="#">Bytt farge</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('background2.css')"><a href="#">Bytt bakgrunnsfarget</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">CSS 3 <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('')"><a href="#">Bytt skrift</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('skrift3.css')"><a href="#">Bytt farge</a></li>
                        <li onclick="swapStyleSheet('background3.css')"><a href="#">Bytt bakgrunnsfarget</a></li>
                    </ul>
    </div>
    <p class="skrift">skrifttypen skal endre seg.</p>
    <p class="skrift">skrifttypen skal endre seg.</p>
    <p class="skrift">skrifttypen skal endre seg.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You question is a little bit confusing, could you elaborate? What do you mean by "1 css file for every single button", do you use a css file for each different button?

Comment: You really should close your tags properly, just saying.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue so far, what happens when you (click) load the new style sheet? it doesn't take effect or you are just looking for a different way in doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, do not swap stylesheet files for starters. You can either:

- have different classes for different situations, and set these classes on your element withs JavaScript. This is quite easy even in vanilla JS, for example:

  `document.getElementById('myButton').classList.add("btn-red");`
- load override stylesheets dynamically, which will override existing styles. So instead of having full-blown, complete stylesheet, just put the modifications in the CSS files, and load it *after* the default stylesheet.

I would definitely recommend the first approach, it is much more maintanable and sane. Most CSS frameworks work the same way, just take a look at Bootstrap ([twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap)) for example.

Comment: Seems like a logical approach. I just hope he gets it.